# Model/Migration creation order matters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have generated 4 models in rails. Now some of them requires columns for foreign keys from each other.

Suppose I have a table User and other table Post. Now do i need to generate the models in order for ex. `User` and then `Post`, so that Posts table could contain `user_id` column in it?

I am not running `rake db:migrate` now. What I'm doing is generating models and specifying the columns that might be necessary.

I want to know is, does `rake db:migrate` takes care of the order automatically and i can create the models in any order? Or as migration files has timestamps attached to it in the file name, it will be processed according to the order of its creation and will give me the error for ex. `user_id foreign key dependency, table Users not found`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no foreign key dependencies in Rails migrations, so as long as you are not creating dependent data for the models in the migrations, it will work correctly.

Comment: If i'm creating user_id in Posts table, will it not check if Users table exists or not?

Comment: No, it will not check for that relation at the migration level.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing the doubt, accepting the answer in 6 mins :)

Comment: Sure, you should still try to keep the order as logical as possible, but if you only create the table definitions, it doesn't matter. You will run into issues if your 1st migration is trying to seed some data requiring the second migration. This is why seed data should be defined in seed.rb or in a bootstrapping task. Hope this helps